# Max date is defaulted to 2013 in v2.1 beta

Tags: mobiscroll

Creating a mobiscroll instance using the following, when I scroll the year wheel it wraps from 2013 to 1912. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? thx

```
dateInput.scroller({
    preset: 'date',
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    dateOrder: 'ddmmyy',
    theme: 'default',
    display: screenWidth < 400 ? 'modal' : 'bubble',
    mode: 'mixed',
    headerText: label + ' date  {value}'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the startyear is equal to the current year minus 100 years and the end year is current year plus 1. The documentation showed wrong numbers! It has been corrected!